# Runtime exception when trying to run Maven project on tomcat v9.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I imported a new project to eclipse. It's a maven project. I don't get any compiler errors. I added a new tomcat server to eclipse, I also added that server in project runtime. Everything should be fine. Except when I try to run a project, I get runtime errors.

> pro 09, 2016 12:30:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/scbl-rest-services]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1404)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1394)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/scbl-rest-services]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
>     ... 6 more

And the list goes on.

I tried every possible solution I could find on the Internet. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: try to remove the tomcat and add new

Comment: What IDE are you using ?If you are using eclipse try configuring new tomcat .If STS then try configuring tc server which is inbuilt in STS.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add some variables used in project, also some arguments to tomcat server. After that, project started in tomcat server without errors and it's working properly.